# Visual Studio Code adding 'prefix0' in Flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently switch from Android Studio to VS Code to work on my Flutter projects but I have an issue with it.

VS Code keeps adding "prefix0." before all classes as soon as I am using auto-completion and I didn't find a way to get rid of it.

I have seen that some VS extensions for CSS can auto-prefix some parts of code but I do not have any CSS extensions.

Thanks